# Getting error "o.a.n.f.r.ConflictResolvingExternalResourceProviderWorker Error during polling for external resources Error" after nifi upgrade

Tags: apache-nifi, upgrade

I have upgraded the NiFi from version 1.16.0 to 1.21.0. I have done all the necessary configurations but after starting the new NiFi version I am getting an error saying "o.a.n.f.r.ConflictResolvingExternalResourceProviderWorker Error during polling for external resources"

Can you please help.

Thanks